# DirectX Recalculate Interior/Exterior Implementation

Tags: directx, 3d-modelling

For my game, I have added "Brushes" which are 3D boxes that will be used to create level geometry. I wanted to add the ability to flip the brushes inside out, so the exterior becomes the interior, etc. I'm pretty sure I know how to do this, but I wanted to make sure this is actually standard practice. First of all, here's a picture of my BrushVolume in engine:

[image]

I generate this BrushVolume via the following code:

```
public void Rebuild()
        {
            /**
             * No faces are present; empty the StaticBrushVolume
             */
            if (this.FaceVisibility == BrushVolumeFaceVisibility.None)
            {
                if (_bufferBinding.Buffer != null)
                {
                    _bufferBinding.Buffer.Dispose();
                }
                this.FaceCount = 0;
                _drawCount = 0;
                return;
            }
            this.FaceCount = CountVisibleFaces(this.FaceVisibility);
            Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[this.FaceCount * 6];
            float width = this.Width;
            float height = this.Height;
            float depth = this.Depth;
            float uvX = width / (float)this.DiffuseMaterial.Width;
            float uvY = height / (float)this.DiffuseMaterial.Height;
            float uvZ = depth / (float)this.DiffuseMaterial.Width;
            // Generate Front Face
            int index = 0;
            if (this.FaceVisibility.HasFlag(BrushVolumeFaceVisibility.Front))
            {
                Vector3 normal = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, uvY), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
            }
            // Generate East Face
            if (this.FaceVisibility.HasFlag(BrushVolumeFaceVisibility.Left))
            {
                Vector3 normal = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(uvZ, uvY), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, -depth), new Vector2(uvZ, 0), normal);

                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, -depth), new Vector2(uvZ, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
            }
            // Generate South Face
            if (this.FaceVisibility.HasFlag(BrushVolumeFaceVisibility.Back))
            {
                Vector3 normal = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, depth), new Vector2(uvX, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, depth), new Vector2(uvX, uvY), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, depth), new Vector2(uvX, 0), normal);
            }
            // Generate West Face
            if (this.FaceVisibility.HasFlag(BrushVolumeFaceVisibility.Right))
            {
                Vector3 normal = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);

                // Clockwise

                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, depth), new Vector2(uvZ, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, depth), new Vector2(uvZ, uvY), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);

                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, depth), new Vector2(uvZ, 0), normal);

                // Counter Clockwise

                //vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
                //vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, depth), new Vector2(uvZ, uvY), normal);
                //vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, depth), new Vector2(uvZ, 0), normal);

                //vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, depth), new Vector2(uvZ, 0), normal);
                //vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                //vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
            }
            // Generate Top Face
            if (this.FaceVisibility.HasFlag(BrushVolumeFaceVisibility.Top))
            {
                Vector3 normal = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, depth), new Vector2(uvX, uvZ), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, depth), new Vector2(0, uvZ), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, depth), new Vector2(uvX, uvZ), normal);
            }
            // Generate Bottom Face
            if (this.FaceVisibility.HasFlag(BrushVolumeFaceVisibility.Bottom))
            {
                Vector3 normal = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, depth), new Vector2(uvX, uvZ), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, depth), new Vector2(0, uvZ), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, depth), new Vector2(uvX, uvZ), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, 0), normal);
                vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
            }
            if (this._bufferBinding.Buffer != null)
            {
                this._bufferBinding.Buffer.Dispose();
            }
            this._drawCount = vertices.Length;
            Buffer vertexBuffer = Buffer.Create(Device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, vertices);
            this._bufferBinding = new VertexBufferBinding(vertexBuffer, 32, 0); // 32 is Vertex Size In Bytes
        }
```

I left a note in there showing my current thinking on how to flip a face from interior to exterior. Quite simply, I was thinking to just invert the winding order. My engine uses clockwise winding by default, so if I were to invert the winding for each face to be counter clockwise, it would appear as an interior in engine. This works, too. However, and it may be a stupid question. But is this standard? I tried Googling how Blender implements "Recalculate Inside", but I can't find anything online discussing the actual implementation details.

Does anyone know if the standard practice for flipping a face from exterior to interior is as simple as reversing the winding order?

Comment: I'm aware that I would also need to flip the normals, and quite possibly even have a different texture uv layout as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that inverting the winding order is how this is achieved. I also had to invert the texture coordinates and normals so that the textures displayed correctly. Here is a gif showing the result of my implementation:

[image]

In that gif I'm just hitting a key to cycle through the "Hull Mode" of the brushvolume.

The source for this example is located [on my pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HxRYhHka):

Here is a brief example of how I invert from exterior to interior, etc.

```
if (this.FaceVisibility.HasFlag(BrushVolumeFaceVisibility.Front))
            {
                if (this.HullMode == BrushVolumeHullMode.Interior)
                {
                    Vector3 normal = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, 0), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, uvY), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, uvY), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                }
                else
                {
                    Vector3 normal = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, -depth), new Vector2(0, 0), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, 0), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, 0), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(uvX, uvY), normal);
                    vertices[index++] = new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, -depth), new Vector2(0, uvY), normal);
                }
            }
```

It should be noted that my implementation is not at all elegant, because I hard coded the flipped state into an if branch, depending upon the hull mode. Software like Blender likely has a way more extravagant way of doing this, because they have to iterate over a much larger (and dynamic) set of triangles. There is likely a fancy algorithm for inverting the winding order and texture coordinates. However, I have no idea what it could be, because there is no material for it online.

If anyone knows a better way to do this, I would really like to see it.